# Android PhotoView - zoom to previous position (x y coordinates and scale)

Tags: android, android-canvas, android-bitmap, android-photoview

I'm using https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView so user can zoom the image and then draw some point.

There is also a function to delete this point. In this case I redraw whole bitmap:

```
matrix = new Matrix();
canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);
setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

But now I want to zoom image to previous position/coordinates.

This should work:

```
setScale(scale, focalX, focalY, false);
```

I know the scale but I need focalX, focalY.

How can I get it? Maybe I should somehow calculate it from the

```
getSuppMatrix(matrix);
```

But I'm not sure if it's possible and how.

Do you have some tips? Help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved by getting matrix

```
getSuppMatrix(matrix);
```

before setting new bitmap

```
setImageBitmap(bmp);
```

And then setting previous matrix

```
setSuppMatrix(matrix);
```